# Excel Formula for many rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel like this

[image: Pls see sample here]

There are around 500 rows , from that I want to get a formula like this,
(Value in A1 enclosed in double quotes, value in A2 enclosed in double quotes  until 500 row)
("AF","AX", until 500 rows)
I tried several options but they didn't help.
Can someone please help?

Comment: Hint: check if you have `TEXTJOIN` function available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You , It worked.

```
="("""&TEXTJOIN(""",""",TRUE,$A$1:$A$249)&""")"
```

Link : [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/404148/excel-columns-to-one-cell) and [extendoffice](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2706-excel-vlookup-return-multiple-values-in-one-cell.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try `TEXTJOIN()` with `Char()` function like-

```
=CHAR(34) & TEXTJOIN(CHAR(34) & ", " & CHAR(34),TRUE,A1:A8) & CHAR(34)
```

[image]